# Сжатие Deflate(GZIP)

Tags: c#, gzip

Информация доступна крупицами, а вопрос большой. Так как не силён в английском - http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html мне особо не помогает.

Суть: имеется блок байтов, сжатый с помощью GZipStream. 
GZipStream оборачивает сжатый блок пакетом данных, в нём содержится первоначальный размер блока, размер сжатого блока и прочие типы сжатия и т.д.

Вопросы:

1. Как правильно получить размеры блока: сжатый и исходный?
2. Если сжимать и распаковывать блоки с помощью GZipStream - мне не нужно обрезать обёртку (байты с обоих сторон), это сделает за меня gZipStream?

Comment: Я что-то не нахожу в описании формата упакованной длины, только неупакованную, да и ту по модулю `2^32`.

Comment: Правильно, как раз и это и надо, для того чтобы под распакованный массив байтов выделить пространство и хранить его для дальнейшего использования. Только я его не смог достать на данный момент + размер от начала и до конца блока (в упакованном файле, состоящим из этих блоков) не нашёл.

Comment: Ну, чтобы выделить массив — может быть. А как вы собираетесь искать конец текущего куска?

Comment: надо прочитать некоторое количество байт вначале файла, отступив сколько-то, затем вернуться в начало файла и откусить кусок указанного размера, затем можно отправить его в GZIP для декомпрессии, выделить динамический массив для распакованного куска, узнать его размер, выделить ровно столько места в массиве распакованных байт ну и далее по списку

Comment: Эээ, а какого «указанного» размера? Нету в заголовке gzip этой информации.

Comment: хмм, т.е. вы хотите сказать что архиватор типа winrar тупо байт за байтом распаковывает файл? что за бред, он должен знать размер блока, который распаковывает. Я упаковал файл, распаковал его винраром - получил исходный размер. прокатывает даже с уже упакованными файлами, размер который при компрессии расширяется, при декомпрессии винраром файл читается и имеет исходный размер. Вин рар знает то что мне нужно, а я нет

Comment: Возможно вы правы, попробую запаковать размер сжатых блоков в эти самые блоки

Comment: Почему должен знать заранее? Вдруг при распаковке есть признак конца? Я ничего похожего в RFC не нашёл.

Comment: Записывать размер блока вряд ли покатит, т. к. при этом не будет распаковываться GZip'ом.

Comment: А вот что делает WinRAR, это как раз интересно, да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эксперимент:

```
$ echo -ne "Hello, " > file1.txt
$ echo "World!" > file2.txt
$ gzip file1.txt
$ gzip file2.txt
$ cat file1.txt.gz file2.txt.gz > file3.txt.gz
$ gzip -d file3.txt.gz
$ cat file3.txt
Hello, World!
$
```

Источник: http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html#file-format

> Файл gzip состоит из серии "членов" (сжатых наборов данных). Формат каждого члена указан далее. Члены просто идут один за другим в файле, без дополнительной информации до, между или после них.

К сожалению, именно на C# не могу это сделать, так как не знаю этого языка.

Можно просто разобрать gzip-файл по байтам и посмотреть. Экспериментальный файл делается командой в шелл:

```
echo -n "hello" | gzip -n > test.txt.gz
```

Флаг `-n` у `echo` значит не добавлять перенос в конце строки, у `gzip` он значит не вставлять в заголовки имя и дату модификации исходного файла. Для простоты. Сжимаем строку `"hello"` Получается следующий файл (`test.txt.gz`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первые два байта это ID1 и ID2 из RFC. Третий (00001000 = 8) это метод компрессии CM (всегда 8, то есть deflate). Четвертый это флаги FLG. Я выделил один флаг зеленым. Если его установить в 1, то это будет значить, что используются дополнительные заголовки. За байтом флагов идут четыре нулевых байта. Это время последней модификации исходного файла MTIME. Оно нулевое из-за флага `-n`. Следующий байт это дополнительные флаги XFL и за ним выделен красным тип операционной системы OS (00000011 = 3, то есть Unix). Вот за этим полем пойдут дополнительные заголовки, если установить нужный бит во флагах. Сейчас же за ним идут сжатые данные, длину которых можно определить, только выполнив декомпрессию, после которых четыре байта CRC32 и только в конце четыре байта ISIZE (выделил синим). То есть ISIZE не находится в заголовке и его позицию нельзя узнать без декомпрессии. У вас остается только вариант использовать экстра-заголовки и вместо ISIZE, и для хранения длины сжатых данных, известной на этапе компрессии, если вы хотите чтобы архив оставался валидным gzip.

Comment: а каков общий размер этих членов в байтах?

Comment: Сумма размеров всех членов :-) В общем, в том вашем первом вопросе ошибочка вышла. Файлы gzip можно просто соединять между собой.

Comment: @Garrus_En, с другой стороны, тогда не понятно, зачем Марк Адлер писал gzjoin.

Comment: соединять то можно, они и соединены в файле, но когда у меня естб файл и мне надо его распаковать, я наверняка не знаю какой кусок от него откусить, чтобы предать анаф.. декомпрессии.  Зачем это нужно? - файл может быть огромным, и не поместиться в оперативной памяти, а если же использовать ресурсы жёсткого диска - получится сильно медленно

Comment: есть мысль при запаковке выделять пру байт и записывать в них первоначальный и сжатый размеры, но это получается двойная работа, где то среди первых восьми байт в блоке уже есть вся эта информация. Вот её надо найти и использовать по прямому назначению

Comment: Насколько я понял, размер несжатых данных содержится в поле ISIZE, а размер сжатых не содержится нигде. Но там поддерживаются "extra field", то ест дополнительные поля заголовка. В таком поле вы можете вручную при сжатии прописать размер сжатых данных. Тогда потоки смогут разобрать куски файла для распаковки.

Comment: какой это по счёту байт?

Comment: ISize находится в 4 байте упакованного блока. Мне удалось его получить из упакованного файла + винрару не мешает его наличие значит вин

Comment: @Garrus_En, вообще-то нет. С полем ISIZE все плохо. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Первоначально мне удалось выбить из сжатого файла поле ISize, позже всё почему-то поломалось. С ним реально что-то не то )

Comment: @Garrus_En, это было совпадением. Это поле идет после сжатых данных, самым последним в "члене" gzip. Его нельзя узнать, не выполняя декомпрессию блока.

Comment: Как я понял мне надо в FLG поставить 00000100, тогда в следующем байте будет зашифровано количество бит, использованных в Экстра, а за ним уже непосредственно эти поля?

Comment: Это будет не в следующем байте (после FLG),  а после байта OS (выделил красным в ответе).

Comment: Кроме того, разумеется, экстра-заголовки должны не переписывать (портить) следующие байты, а вставляться между OS и ними. Кроме того, экстра-заголовки должны быть сформированы по правилам RFC.